# What's the difference between "at least [number]" and "[number] or more"?

Tags: phrase-usage, numbers

> A person who has **at least 2** heads isn't normal.
>
> A person who has **2 or more** heads isn't normal.

Is there a difference between the usage of "at least [number]" and "[number] or more"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They mean the same thing! In both instances, "at least [number]"/"[number] or more", you're saying that anything greater than or equal to the [number] is acceptable. Or, in this case, unacceptable.